# Samsung SVG audio format (of old voice pens, like SVR M920)

Tags: audio, audio-recording

The problem is, that I have got a voice pen recording in *.SVG format.
All I know is that it was recorded long ago and no CD with orginal voice pen software is available to find. Also there is no device itself - only the recording.

After some googling I found out:
 1. This recording must have been done with some old Samsung voice pen
 2. The software name, that might help to play or convert the recording must be "Voice Manager Pro M92x/M93x" of something like that
 3. The software from official Samsung site, that is named "Voice Manager" or "JetVoiceMail" is unable to play *.svg recordings - only *.cvf that I don't need
 4. The official site of SIMS voice pens http://simsvalley.com now is useless - there is hosted a hotel agency
 5. archive.org did manage to find the old version of simsvalley.com but not all the pages were stored, so there can be found no help too.
 6. http://voicepen.narod.ru/download.html seems to be a perfect solution, but not a single link is alive

Any ideas what can I try?
Maybe somebody can share that software with me?

Comment: I was able to find some working links, but I don't know whether they can be useful. ftp://fvd.ru/drivers/Samsung/VoiceRecorder/voice_manager_2.rar ftp://fvd.ru/drivers/Samsung/VoiceRecorder/voce_manager_plus.rar http://www.sql.ru/photos/Tech-Ed03/vmpro920.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very grateful to you, [and31415](https://superuser.com/users/289138/and31415)!
I managed to play the SVG recording and convert it to WAV with Voice Manager Pro, as I had guessed before.
In order not to lose those pieces of software in future here is the [permanent link](ftp://abbradar.net/english/voice_manager/) to them.

If anybody is interested, the mentioned SVG file can be found [here](ftp://abbradar.net/english/audio/svg).

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)